# Disable email field on WooCommerce customer account details

Tags: wordpress

I am making a wordpress website i have one problem if someone know about this.  what I wanted is that they can register their email upon checkout and then once their account has been completely created, they cannot change their email anymore on the Account Details page. Would that be possible?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The only way to prevent modifying the email address would be to copy the **form-edit-account** into the WooCommerce subdirectory of your theme directory and delete the email field from the WooCommerce template **\myaccount\form-edit-account.php**  You'd would then need to remove the email as a required field using this filter.  You can't really show the field and prevent users from updating it that is the only issue with this solution.  You could add in function that displayed the user's email address somewhere else in the edit account form or on the my account page to get around this.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_save_account_details_required_fields', 'remove_required_email_address');

function remove_required_email_address( $required_fields ) {
    unset($required_fields['account_email']);

    return $required_fields;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, from this code email address field will be disable / remove from checkout page ?

Comment: Actually i am doing when user is already login in website then user unable to change email address from checkout page .

Comment: I dont want to remove that i just want to disable that so that user can only see the email , he cant change that

Comment: @Alex this will remove it from the My Account page.  It's impossible to disable the email field.  You'd need to remove it and then add it back in but display text only.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way that works for me.

I use a hook in 'woocommerce_after_edit_account_form' to add a bit of javascript at the end of the page, this javascript makes the field "account_email" read only, so the user can't update it.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_edit_account_form', 'disable_edit_email_address' );

function disable_edit_email_address( ) {
    $script = '<script type="text/javascript">'.
              'var account_email = document.getElementById("account_email");'.
              'if(account_email) { '.
              '     account_email.readOnly = true; '.
              '     account_email.className += " disable-input";'.
              '}'.
              '</script>';
    echo $script;
}
```

Additionally, you can see, i use the style "disable-input" for opacity the input:

```
.disable-input {
  opacity: .6;
}
```

Regards

Comment: With this solution, there is always a risk that a tech savvy user would open devtools and remove the Readonly attribute, which would mean that they can change the value of the field.