# Disable or make read only the fields from edit account pages in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, readonly, account

Currently the Edit Account Details page have these fields: First Name, Last Name, Email address, Current Password & New Password.

Now I need to disable the First Name, Last Name, Email address fields for customers user only. I am using Flatsome WP theme and Woocommerce plugins.

How can I do this?

Comment: I posted one way in in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49510540/disable-email-field-on-woocommerce-customer-account-details/57081151#57081151. The solution is based in use ahook in 'woocommerce_after_edit_account_form' and add a bit of javascript. Regards

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Update**

> For [edit](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/#section-1) "Account details" fields (email field), you will need to edit [`myaccount/form-edit-account.php`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/release/3.4/templates/myaccount/form-edit-account.php) template file as those fields are hard coded in the template

> You will have to add a **readonly** attribute to the related input fields like in this extract example:

> ```
> <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--first form-row form-row-first">
> ```

```
    <label for="account_first_name"><?php esc_html_e( 'First name', 'woocommerce' ); ?>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
    <input type="text" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="account_first_name" id="account_first_name" autocomplete="given-name" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $user->first_name ); ?>" readonly />
</p>
```

> **Official documentation:** [Overriding templates via a theme](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/)

For  My account > edit billing address, the following code **will make readonly** the billing fields first name, last name and email:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_billing_fields', 'readonly_billing_account_fields', 25, 1 );
function readonly_billing_account_fields ( $billing_fields ) {
    // Only my account billing address for logged in users
    if( is_account_page() ){

        $readonly = ['readonly' => 'readonly'];

        $billing_fields['billing_first_name']['custom_attributes'] = $readonly;
        $billing_fields['billing_last_name']['custom_attributes'] = $readonly;
        $billing_fields['billing_email']['custom_attributes'] = $readonly;
    }
    return $billing_fields;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

> **Note:** To enable that on checkout page too, Just remove `if( is_account_page() ){` and the closing bracket `}` before `return $billing_fields;`.

---

To **remove those 3 fields** you will use:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_billing_fields', 'remove_billing_account_fields', 25, 1 );
function remove_billing_account_fields ( $billing_fields ) {
    // Only my account billing address for logged in users
    if( is_account_page() ){
        unset($billing_fields['billing_first_name']);
        unset($billing_fields['billing_last_name']);
        unset($billing_fields['billing_email']);
    }
    return $billing_fields;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Is it possible to do that for certain customer roles only?

Comment: @AmirNo-Family Use additionally (in the if statement) `&& current_user_can('your_user_role')` replacing `your_user_role` by the certain customer role for example.

Comment: The question actually asks about disabling fields, not making them read only.  Changing readonly to disabled  in the solution above will disable the fields.  I really only make the distinction because, if you are looking to stop the customer editing any of the fields, billing_state is a dropdown so, you will need to disable the field, not make it readonly - refer to stackoverflow.com/questions/368813/…

Answer (score 1):

You can easily disable various fields from the WooCommerce Account Page by adding this to your theme's `functions.php`

```
function my_remove_checkout_fields($fields) {
    unset( $fields ['billing'] ['billing_first_name'] );
    unset( $fields ['billing'] ['billing_last_name'] );
    unset( $fields ['billing'] ['billing_email'] );

    // Any other fields you want to unset...

    return $fields;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'my_remove_checkout_fields' );
```

The documentation for customizing fields can be found [here](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/).

Comment: Thanks for your replay. I have used your code but it didn't work. my problem was edit-account page and the input field id name is id="account_first_name", id="account_last_name" and id="account_email". But you mentioned about billing fields.