# How to avoid users from editing some billing address fields in WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, account

I am using [Disable or make read only the fields from edit account pages in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52448313/disable-or-make-read-only-the-fields-from-edit-account-pages-in-woocommerce/52449988#52449988) 2nd code snippet, to make readonly the billing fields first name, last name and email on My account > edit billing address.
This Code works in account page.

Can I to use the same code but for the checkout billing fields?

What I should I have to modify?

Comment: Added an update in the original linked thread… So to enable that on checkout page too, just remove `if( is_account_page() ){` and the closing bracket `}` before `return $billing_fields;`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps change:

`if( is_user_logged_in() && is_account_page() ){`

To:

`if ( is_user_logged_in() && ( is_account_page() || is_checkout() ) ) {`